# What is required in an apps manifest to make it a default?

Tags: android

I know that in order for an app to be set as default, you need something in your manifest and in your code. What is required to make an app a default for the phone/contacts app or the browser app?

Comment: You cannot make an app be a default app for anything, such as phone/contacts or browser. What you *can* do is have an `<activity>` with the appropriate `<intent-filter>` for certain operations, such as `ACTION_VIEW` on `https` URLs for a browser. Then, the *user* will have an option of making your app be the default for `Intents` matching that `<intent-filter>`

Comment: I need to know how to do that

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html